# Inserting a blank row after each row in vba for excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using the following code:

```
Sub del_row()
Dim r As Long, y As Long
y = Sheet1.Range("A" & Sheet1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For r = 2 To y Step 2
    Rows(r).Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Next r
End Sub
```

This works, but stops at row 1020 and I'm not sure why. Is there a way I can modify this to continue until there is no more data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are inserting or deleting rows, work from the bottom up.

```
Sub del_row()    
    Dim r As Long, y As Long
    y = Sheet1.Range("A" & Sheet1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For r = y To 2 Step -1    '<~~ this is the magic
        Sheet1.cells(r, 1).entirerow.Insert Shift:=xlDown    
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I can't believe I forgot about that.